# Impedance of the infinitely long circuit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

Is there a way to find impedance of the infinite circuit like this?

[image]

It will be much simpler if one has either parallel or series combination but here is both.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10615/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/73713/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard trick is to split off the circuit after the first link,

[image]

and treat the 'tail' as another copy of the circuit itself. This means that the impedance $Z$ of the whole circuit must satisfy

$$
Z=2Z_1+\frac{1}{\frac{1}{Z_2}+\frac{1}{Z}}.
$$

This gives a quadratic equation in $Z$ which is easy enough to solve.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty A good reference that illustrates the infinite ladder network, and how to solve it as you have shown is Feynman's lectures on physics; I believe volume 2. Feynman calls it the *Characteristic Impedance*. What is interesting (to me) is that one starts off with a linear circuit, and by expanding to infinity one gets a nonlinear system.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty ... and the challenge I've periodically pursued is to devise an estimator that can take input/output measurements of $Z$ and estimate the parameters $Z_1$ and $Z_2$. Have you seen this done?