# Are continued fractions ever of use in physics?

Tags: mathematics

Do you know of any instance when a [continued fraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) is of help or necessary do describe a natural phenomenon?

Comment: This post (v2) seems like a list question.

Comment: You may interest in the example [**here**](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/10615/what-would-be-the-effective-resistance-of-the-ladder-of-resistors-having-n-steps)

Comment: One more use: [method of continued fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_continued_fractions) in quantum scattering theory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a connection that I suspect minimizes the number of intermediate steps between the physics and the continued fractions:

If you want to study angular momentum, then you want to study the representation theory of $SU(2)$.  This will force you to study Clebsch-Gordan coefficients, Wigner symbols, Racah symbols, etc.  Locating the zeros of such symbols often requires solving one or more Pell equations (i.e. Diophantine equations of the form $X^2-nY^2=1$).  The solutions to $X^2-nY^2=1$ form a free abelian group of rank 1, so to find all solutions, it suffices to find a generator of that group.  That solution can be found as a convergent of the continued fraction for $\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: Can you provide references for further reading on the topic?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty:  Were you asking for references on the application of continued fractions to Pell's equation, or the application of Pell's equation to Wigner symbols, etc?

Comment: both topics, really.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty:  The application of continued fractions to Pell's equation is standard fare in textbooks on number theory, and I'm sure there are a jillion to choose from.  (I think I recall that Stark's book spends more  time on this than most.)  For the application of Pell's equation to representation theory, here is a pretty much randomly chosen example:  http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0305-4470/26/11/011